# Dropdownlist Error. Unable to select from dropdownlist

Tags: java, android

I have one Dropdown Spinner in my Android project. Previously it work fine, but after i change some code it had some bugs and i can't find out.

When I click on the spinner, the list dropdown and there is option inside for select. But when i select any option, the spinner doesn't set the spinner to any option. And when i log the selectedPosition, it show "-1"

Below is some of my codes. Please do help me out and tell me what is the problem that make this happen.

```
public void getDefaultPallet(String pasted) {

    String pass = getLookupTable(this);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(pass);
        String receive_fields = jsonObject.getString("PalletType");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(receive_fields);

        if (pasted.equals("")){
            list.add("");
            passvalue.add("");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            passvalue.add(jobj.getString("Key"));
            list.add(jobj.getString("Value"));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The way i get ArrayList<>;

```
public void dialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(AddTallyInActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_assign_pallet);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    dialog_spinner = dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_dialog);
    dialog_ok = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_ok);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    dialog_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    for (int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
        if (list.get(i).equals(default_pallet)){
            dialog_spinner.setSelection(i);
        }
    }

    dialog_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (dialog_et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                dialog_et.setError("Do not blank.");
            } else {
              tv_palletno.setText(dialog_et.getText().toString());
              tv_pallettype.setText(passvalue.get(dialog_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()));

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}
```

The DropdownSpinner in Dialog.

Comment: use `setonitemselectedlistener()`

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
tv_pallettype.setText(dialog_ok.get);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `dialog_ok.setOnClickListener` use `dialog_ok.setOnItemSelectedListener` like below:

```
dialog_ok.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            if (dialog_et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                dialog_et.setError("Do not blank.");
            } else {
                tv_palletno.setText(dialog_et.getText().toString());
                tv_pallettype.setText(passvalue.get(position));

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try by moving my adapter to the main coding. Its work. No idea how it works. Please anyone give me an explanation.